# Copy list of files to new names

Tags: batch

**Windows 7 Pro**

I want to copy a series of files, all named "cover" from different directories to a single directory, and give them all new names. I need help with either of the below options:

**Option 1**
Use a batch file to copy the source files to a single directory as "cover1", "cover2", etc., then rename by hand.

I can use the below one-line batch file, but it copies files sequentially to the name "cover" in the directory "A", resulting in just one final file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (Coverscopy.txt) do copy "%%L" A
```

I presume I should use a loop to add a number to the filename, but I'm afraid I don't seem to know how to vary the file name with each cycle.

**Second option**
Use a batch filed that draws from a CSV file with columns for the original file address and the desired new name.

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start with this.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to copy from one dir to another only files corresponding to a given mask. It's not written for use of multiple source dirs but it can be helpfull.

```
@echo off
set p="C:\temp"
SET filemask=%p%\*cover*.txt
SET destfolder="C:\temp2"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /od /a-d /b %filemask%') DO COPY "%p%\%%a" "%destfolder%"
echo Done!
PAUSE
```